# How to link g++ itself to my project?

Tags: c++, linker, g++, gnu, ld

so to make things clear, my goal is to write a code which can save crucial parts of its own code (like the main func or other classes or stuff like that)
which i will be just copying them inside a class, then i want my program to add/remove some codes (func, obj, class, ...) using user input and after all of that i want it to regenerate that code again and create the class that holds the crucial parts of the code automatically and i want it to compile that and delete itself. 
So i have all of the above planned and figured out except the part which i want it to compile that code, is there anyway to link g++ to my code? but i know that g++ has a main func, wouldnt that create problems with my main func?
+ i cant use the compiler on the existing system and i cant have the compiler as a separate executable...

Comment: You can't just link g++ in.  Executables can't be linked into other executables, and g++ is more than just an executable anyway (it requires a large collection of files in order to work).  Best way to do this is either to use an external copy of GCC to create dynamic objects which can be loaded, or to generate code with LLVM.

Comment: ik that g++ is an exe but cant we use the precompiled binary.... and i just mentioned i cant use external stuff... pls read the txt... what is llvm?

Comment: Ok so ive googled LLVM, seems like a good choice but would i have to write my own compiler using the llvm libraries?

Comment: Why can't you use external stuff?  That's going to make things incredibly difficult.

Comment: Tbh im writing a trojan for a school project and am trying to create a botnet using some pcs and i want it to be as realistic as possible sothe computer that my code is targetting may not have any compilers + i dont like 2 files ;)

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you are completely unprepared for the realities of dynamic code generation and you should try a completely different approach.  Just trying to help here.

Comment: Ik that im a little bit naive but can you please give me some hints on where to start?

Comment: Use a different language.  Interpretive languages, such as scripts, are more adaptable than compiled languages.  Compiled languages are generally not designed to dynamically change their code or behavior.

Comment: You could mitigate by having your C++ compiled program execute a script or interpretive language.  Be aware that the target platform needs the interpretive support (like JVM, and Python interpreter).

Comment: @shervin: I don't know why you wanted to have dynamic code generation in the first place.  If you can explain the motivating reason behind that decision, it would be easier to point out alternatives.  Dynamic code generation is a very rare choice in software—especially C++—and there is usually a simpler way to achieve the same goals.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews using a different language isnt an option for me, srry. by doing this with c++ i want to gain some experience.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: the reason for the dynamic code generation is to change code patterns to avoid getting caught by AVs(anti-viruses), cause they check snippets of ur code with some kind of database.

Comment: @shervin: This is too far beyond your current ability.  I suggest studying the following subjects: CS foundations, OS theory, compiler design and construction, and assembly language programming.  This will give you the background you would need in order to accomplish such a task.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: ill google some books. But if you have some online resources that you can share i would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *link* your code with a compiler.  You could *package* your executable with a compiler.  Your code could generate C++ source code and then call the compiler to generate a new executable.

Keep in mind that most compilers are huge in size.  Try installing G++ or MinGW on your system to get an understanding.

For more details, search the internet for "Compiler Design Theory" which will give you information about translating languages like C++ into an executable.

Also, you will need to have the Operating System launch the new executable (and kill the present instance).  This will take some research into the Operating System's API.

IMHO, the best method is to use an interpretive or script language.  The alternate is to have your C++ program execute a script or pieces of a script.

**Edit 1:  very low level**
At the very lowest level, microcode (the command bytes that a processor processes) needs to be generated.

The steps would be:

1. Generate the microcode and place in some known location in memory
   (that you have access to and is has execution privilege).
2. Transfer execution to the microcode, remembering to push the return
   address on the stack.

The hard part is generating the microcode, especially adjusting the target addresses of all the branch instructions (unless you use something called Position Independent Code).

You could spend many months or years writing code that generates the micro code or figure out how to use pieces of compilers (like CLang or G++).

Comment: yep thats pretty much it, but i think cuz the user runs my code for the first time ill have the privileges that the user has and if he is root i think i can change the ip register on the cpu to run the generated code otherwise i will need to code some assembly to use some long jmps which all can be handled except the generation part :(

Comment: I think you mean "machine code" instead of "microcode".  Microcode is a lower-level set of instructions which is not normally accessible at all.